# How to map uid in users table data to the entityid in feild table to retrieve data of the users in drupal7

Tags: database

I would like to retrieve data related to users with the uid in users table.

But the uid is not mapped in the feild_data tables which has entity_id and entity_type.

How are these two ids mapped in drupal database 7

Comment: what is the role of the uid reference for entity in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `field_data_*` tables, when the `entity_type` is **node**, the `entity_id` & `revision_id` are the foreign keys into the node table. You can use this to `JOIN` into the users table.

```
  //@TODO: Replace field_data_* with the field table in question
  $fields = db_select('field_data_*', 'f');
  $fields->join('node', 'n', "n.nid = f.entity_id AND n.vid = f.revision_id AND f.entity_type = 'node'");
  $fields->join('users', 'u', "u.uid = n.uid");
  $new = $fields
    ->fields('f')
    ->fields('u',array('uid'))
    ->execute()->fetchAll();
```